# Error when calculating time difference between events in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, time

Want to calculate the elapsed time between KeyCount1 = 1 and = 27, Using the time module i can find the start time and the stop time 'this bit works'. However when i try and find the elapsed time by simply subtracting (Start1 - Stop1) i get an error saying that i'm referencing Start1 before its assigned, despite the fact i just assigned it... or so i thought.

```
    if KeyCount1 == 1:
        Start1 = int(round(time.time()))
        print(Start1)
    if KeyCount1 == 27:
        Stop1 = int(round(time.time()))
        print(Stop1)
        TotalT1 = Stop1 - Start1
        print(TotalT1)
```

Comment: how do you use this code? I think 27 appears befor 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using a global variable, the problem was that each time the function iterates it forgot what Start1 was. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: If you have a solution which uses a global - you almost certainly have the wrong solution: Especially if your code gets more complex, so think about using a class with methods. Once you have a class and instances of the class - you can retain information between 'function' calls (since a method is simply a function attached to a class). Normal functions never retain information between calls (as you have now found out).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but in the context for my program, other variables in that function need to be reset when the function executes.

Comment: No reason you can't do all of that in a class. A method on a class has the same capability as a function, with the benefit of persistant data.

Answer (score 1):

use datetime module instead

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

start = datetime.now()
time.sleep(5)
end = datetime.now()

total = end-start

print total.total_seconds()
```